# Idle thread time in GLFW 3.0 / C++

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, glfw

I'm trying to coerce GLFW 3.0 to stop nuking my CPU before moving forward with it as a framework to facilitate learning the API. I took the example from http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html and started searching around for means by which to limit it.

Presently, what I've gotten to work is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(void)
{
    typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;
    typedef std::chrono::milliseconds milliseconds;

    Clock::time_point currentTime, newTime;
    milliseconds frameTime;

    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        currentTime = Clock::now();

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();

        newTime = Clock::now();

        frameTime = std::chrono::duration_cast<milliseconds>(newTime - currentTime);

        if(frameTime.count() < 16)
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(milliseconds(16 - frameTime.count()));

        std::cout << "Frame time: " << frameTime.count() << "ms" << std::endl;
}

glfwTerminate();
return 0;
```

}

Since GLFW already limits itself to 60fps, I thought that might work. And, indeed, it chops my CPU usage in half while the main loop runs. That might be good enough for now, but what I really want to know is:

How does one coax GLFW to wait for a signal and release the CPU instead of just roasting its tires on a while loop? I can't imagine it lacks that feature entirely.

Comment: Nicol Bolas' answer is right on spot. But say you don't want to implement a program that displays some animation, i.e. only changes its contents in creation to user input, then (and only then when your idle loop is allowed to stop for lengths of time) you can use *glfwWaitEvents* instead of *glfwPollEvents*.

Comment: Thank you very much! That, like Nicol's suggestion to use yield instead of sleep_for, is a technical answer I had been hoping for in addition to the other useful guidance below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't. Usually, your program actually does stuff for that time. If you don't have stuff to do, then you yield some time to other processes. If no other processes are available to run, you just swallow it until you're ready to go.

Renderers generally try to render as fast as possible, because they will generally not be able to outrun the GPU. That's how most games work; they try to execute as fast as possible. They may have timers to do some yielding if the CPU is much faster than they expect, but more often than not, they just let the renderer run.

Also, expecting [`sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) to actually return in `milliseconds(16 - frameTime.count())` time is not reasonable. It's only a minimum estimate, not a requirement.

It's better to use [`yield`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) for that instead.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't expect sleep_for to do anything that could be deemed precise, I was just toying around with chrono and what C++11 permits versus trying to involve Boost and actually committing more time to this silly task. =)

Comment: But basically, what you're saying is, "don't worry about it"? I guess As with the Blue Book's GLTools library, I'm concerned at abstracting too far for too long. So if GLFW is going to create a situation where, unless I'm rendering sufficiently complex stuff, a simple while is going to continue to idle away at 100% CPU usage, perhaps there's a cleaner approach?

Comment: @musasabi: Maybe you need to ask what you're trying to learn: how to keep the CPU usage low, or how to use OpenGL? Because those are orthogonal to one another. You can learn all about OpenGL while knowing nothing about CPU usage, or you can learn a lot about how to yield CPU time, while knowing nothing about OpenGL. They really have nothing to do with one another. If you're trying to learn "how to make a game engine" all at once or something, you're just going to overload yourself with pointless details. *Focus* on learning one thing until you're ready to move on.

Comment: Indeed. I'm (sometimes) needlessly preoccupied with not wasting time. I'd like to be working on something that, after a few dozen tutorials, while having perhaps rewritten each time, I could ultimately turn around and use to _start_ building a simple FPS engine or so. Getting a framework like GLFW up and running in a way that doesn't make me want to watch my CPU temperature while it runs seemed a little more oblique in that regard. =)

Comment: @musasabi: If you can't run one of your CPU cores at 100% without having to watch your CPU's temperature, you have *larger* problems than GLFW. Does your computer not have adequate cooling? It's not so much "don't worry about it" as "you're doing the right thing". Except for using `sleep_for`.

Comment: Hahaha, touche. Paranoia suits no one. =D Yes, my core temp is fine. Just that, ya know, if you saw any old process chomping your CPU like that, you'd hunt it down and kill it with fire, for lack of a better metaphor, haha. But, considering I added sleep_for in an attempt to pursue this hacky solution to what wasn't really a problem, I'll take your endorsement and move forward with confidence. Thank you. =)